# Adding separator in ArcGIS python add-in toolbar?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, python-addin

I am trying to separate two sets of button tools in a python add-in toolbar. I am trying to make a toolbar like existing arcmap toolbar where different classes of tools separated by "|".

Can this be done in python add in toolbar?

Answer (score 6):

You will need to edit your config.xml and add:

```
separator="true"
```

to the button that you want the separator to appear before, like I have done near the end of the line of code below:

```
<Toolbar caption="RJSS Toolbar" category="RJSS Addin" id="RJSS.toolbar" showInitially="true"><Items><Button refID="RJSS.button1" /><Button refID="RJSS.button2" separator="true"/></Items></Toolbar>
```

Comment: I tried the separator property. But after installation it is not showing up in the toolbar. My edits of the config.xml is below: `<Toolbars>
        <Toolbar caption="Fishnet Analysis Tool" category="CrashAnalysisToolbar" id="CrashToolBox_addin.toolbar" showInitially="true"><Items><Button refID="CrashToolBox_addin.button" /><Button refID="CrashToolBox_addin.button_1" /><Button refID="CrashToolBox_addin.button_5" separator="true"/><Button refID="CrashToolBox_addin.button_6" /></Items></Toolbar>
        </Toolbars>
    <Menus>
        </Menus>
    </ArcMap></AddIn></ESRI.Configuration>`